# onclick usage on button

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have a **HTML** form with 3 buttons:

```
<html:form modelAttribute="registration" id="registration-form" formUrl="/registrationForm">
<input type="hidden" name="id"/>
<html:field name="voucherID" labelCode="label.voucherID" type="text"/>
<html:field name="programID" labelCode="label.programID" type="text"/>
<html:field name="quantity" labelCode="label.quantity" type="text"/>
<html:field name="active" labelCode="label.active" type="checkBox"/>

<div class="form-actions">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><spring:message code="button.add"/></button>
    <button type="reset" class="btn"><spring:message code="button.cancel"/></button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" onclick="remove()"><spring:message code="button.delete"/></button>
</div>
</html:form>
```

**Javascript** :

```
<head>
<%@ include file="header.jsp"%>
<title><spring:message code="title.registration"/></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function remove(){
    alert('test');
    var form = document.forms[0];
    form.action = "deleteRegistration";
    form.submit();
}
</script>
</head>
```

What I am trying to do is, whenever user press the delete button it should change the value of action to `deleteRegistration`. However I can't make this code works, even the alert function is never triggered at all. Where did I do wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Funny little thing, the `remove()` method will run on `this` object, rename the method to _remove or anything else and it should work as expected.

Comment: Thanks a bunch it works as expected. Is remove a reserved word ?

Comment: remove() is a "reserved" method

Answer (score 0):

Try changin this:

`<button type="button" class="btn" onclick="javascript: remove();"><spring:message code="button.delete"/></button>`

Comment: `javascript` is required only when using `href`

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function remove(){
    alert('test');
    var form = document.forms[0];
    form.action = "deleteRegistration";
    form.submit();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
        <form id="registration-form" action="">
            <div class="form-actions">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">submit</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn">something</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn" onclick="remove()">remove</button>
            </div>
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```